# Missing feature in Q-Dir

Tags: windows-10, qdir

Since the second to last update of Q-Dir (amazing file explorer!), a very much used feature disappeared: 
*The free space in the common status bar at the bottom*.

Using Win 10, Q-Dir Version 7.78 x64, build 16299 x64, from PortableApps

Note that I have also downloaded the zipped portable version from [the developer's site](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir) and it has v7.78 with the status bar (that is where I got the image from).
That would work fine, but I prefer the version from PortableApps, to have it included in its launcher, etc.
It is likely a setting that I cannot find, and which changed automatically upon a recent update.

**How can I recover this?**

I am attaching images.

General view of Q-Dir:
[image]

Bottom left part of the status bar:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the new version?

Comment: @music2myear - Yes. And I checked menu options one by one. I did not find it... I may have missed it, though.

Comment: Do the Changelogs note these features have been removed? What do the logs show?

Comment: Install the older version of Q-Dir.....https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=OLD

Comment: @Moab - It is not a matter of versions, please see updated OP.
The feature was not removed, it is likely a setting I cannot find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the OP,
I have also downloaded the zipped portable version from the developer's site and it has v7.78 with the status bar.
I have transferred files `Q-Dir.ini` and `start.qdr` (the last one probably irrelevant here) from the version from `SoftwareOK.com` to the target version of `PortableApps`, and it worked fine.
I could diff to find out the culprit.